# Is it possible to programatically create column aliases in a report

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to answer question 15 on here http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_hard_questions.

This question, "Identify the three most important cities. Show the break down of top level product category against city." is a bit poorly worded, but I'm taking it to mean a report showing the 3 cities with the highest value total orders, broken down into parent product categories and a total.

I ended up with the below:

```
select * from
(
select * from 
(
select city, sum(accessories) as accessories, sum(bikes) as bikes, sum(clothing) as clothing, sum(components) as components, sum(total) as total from
(
select address.city, decode(ppcat.name, 'Accessories', sod.unitprice*sod.orderqty) as accessories, decode(ppcat.name, 'Bikes', sod.unitprice*sod.orderqty) as bikes, decode(ppcat.name, 'Clothing', sod.unitprice*sod.orderqty) as clothing, decode(ppcat.name, 'Components', sod.unitprice*sod.orderqty) as components, sod.unitprice*sod.orderqty as total from salesorderheader soh
inner join address on (soh.shiptoaddressid = address.addressid or soh.shiptoaddressid = address.addressid)
inner join salesorderdetail sod on soh.salesorderid = sod.salesorderid
inner join productaw paw on sod.productid = paw.productid
inner join productcategory pcat on paw.productcategoryid = pcat.productcategoryid
inner join productcategory ppcat on pcat.parentproductcategoryid = ppcat.productcategoryid
)
group by city
)
order by total desc
) where rownum <= 3
```

The problem is, in the imaginary scenario that additional parent product categories were added, my report would need manually updating... I can't figure out if it's possible, with a different approach, to autopopulate the column headings with the parent product categories.

I don't want rows with duplicated cities, or to use sql that wouldn't work in the context SQLzoo (i.e., would have to use Oracle Developer or somesuch).

Comment: a google search on `oracle pivot queries` may lead to happiness.

Comment: Maybe make cities the columns, and categories the rows? That way your columns are constant.